# Exclude Files in the root but not in subfolders

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to copy only Extra User folders from C:\?

Example.

Exclude all System and Hidden folders (Program Files, Users, Windows, and all other hidden folders) Then only exclude .txt .log .exe ect... from the ROOT ONLY but copy if they are in subfolders?

This is what I have so far

```
$asset = Read-Host "What is the Asset Number?"
$useraiu = Read-Host "What is the user's AIU?"

$source = "\\$asset\C$\"
$dest = "C:\Temp\Dest"

$excludedFolders = '_SMSTaskSequence','inetpub','Program Files','Program Files (x86)','Swsetup','Users','Windows','CCM','Notes'

$myFolders = Get-ChildItem  -Path "\\$asset\C$\" -Directory | where { $_ -notin $excludedFolders }

$myFolders | foreach { robocopy $_  $dest /S /Z /MT /XJD /XA:SH /log+:"\\server\path\path\%asset%-to-%computername%-Transfer-Log.log" /NP /FP /V /TEE}

Read-Host "Press ENTER to quit"
```

I get this output from Robocopy

```
 Log File : \\server\path\path\%asset%-to-%computername%-Transfer-Log.log

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Mon Jun 08 11:11:28 2015

   Source : C:\WINDOWS\system32\Temp\
     Dest : C:\Temp\Dest\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /V /FP /TEE /S /COPY:DAT /Z /NP /XJD /XA:SH /MT:8 /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2015/06/08 11:11:28 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory C:\WINDOWS\system32\Temp\
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Childitem` automatically excludes hidden folders.  If you need to include them, use the `-Force` parameter.  If you want folders with the 'System' attribute, you can then pipe this to `where { $_.Attributes -contains 'System' }`.  However, I don't think that will work here, because the folders you named don't have the 'System' attribute (at least on my Windows 8.1 system).

If you have a list of the exact folders you want to exclude, you can use a `where` clause to exclude that.

```
$excludedFolders = 'Users','Windows','Program Files','Program Files (x86)'

$myFolders = gci -Path 'C:\' -Directory | where { $_ -notin $excludedFolders }
```

At this point, $myFolders is the list of non-hidden directories under C:\, excluding the ones you specified.  You can then use `foreach` to do your copy.

```
$myFolders | foreach { yourCopyFunction -Source $_ }
```

Comment: When you have the `$myFolders | foreach { yourCopyFunction -Source $_ }` Does the yourcopyfunction mean that I could use robocopy.exe? or do I need to use Copy-Item?

Comment: If I use this line `$myFolders = Get-ChildItem  -Path "\\$asset\C$\" -Directory | where { $_ -notin $excludedFolders }` How and where do I put the `where { $_.Attributes -contains 'System' }` to exclude System Folders? I added my code to the original question.

Comment: `robocopy.exe` is what I would use.  Or you can use `Copy-Item`.  Or `xcopy`.  Or any other command; the folder to copy will be in `$_`.  I meant to say that you don't use the `$_.Attributes` line, because `C:\Windows` and `C:\Users` and `C:\Program Files` don't have the *System* attribute.

Comment: I updated my question with the new code. Looks like the $myFolders gets a correct list of Folders to copy. But in my robocopy command its not using the `\\computername\c$` path for the remote computer for the source to copy. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You might get better help if you asked that second part as a new question, as it's more about robocopy than powershell.